# Applescript run Safari in background

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that is now doing what I want it to do: Open a specific URL, close the page and wait 2 seconds then do it again.  The script works.

The problem is that when I run this on my machine, and I am trying to do something else at the same time, the Safari windows keeps popping up. I would really like to run this in the background so that I can continue to work on whatever I am doing.

The code I have is:

```
set theURL to "https://sites.google.com/site/whatever/"

repeat 100 times
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        try
            tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab --with properties {URL:theURL}
            set URL of document 1 to theURL
        on error
            open location theURL
        end try
        delay 2
        try
            close window 1
        end try
    end tell

    tell application "Safari"
        quit
    end tell

    delay 1
end repeat
```

Anyone have a solution to this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari is coming to the front because you are activating it within the loop.

```
repeat 100 times
    tell application "Safari"
        if not (exists document 1) then reopen
        set URL of document 1 to "https://sites.google.com/site/whatever/"
        delay 2
        close window 1
        quit
    end tell
    delay 1
end repeat
```

EDIT

```
set myURLs to {"https://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com/"}

repeat with aUrl in myURLs
    repeat 100 times
        tell application "Safari"
            if not (exists document 1) then reopen
            set URL of document 1 to aUrl
            delay 2
            close window 1
            quit
        end tell
        delay 1
    end repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: Is there a way to take this and run a series in succession.  For example if this is version1 and I the same script with a different url as version2, could I have script that says run version1, when done, run version2?

Comment: There is no need for two scripts, just add another loop.

Comment: I have 8 URLs. If I do this your way I guess I should increase the delay so that all of them open before I close them.  Or could I just put another repeat sequence after the first one?

Comment: Just include all 8 URLs in the myURLs list

Comment: adayzdone that works famously.  Thanks so much.  This is allowing me to run this overnight without intervention.  Yea!!!!!